# Pin cloth to model

Tags: modifiers, cloth-simulation

How do I make pinning follow a model? What object should I select for the hook modifier? In my case the origin does not move. There are only rotations. I am tracing the image series of a running human by Eadweard Muybridge.

[image].

Answer (score 26):

You can use an empty with vertex parenting:

1. Select a vertex on your non-cloth object and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor to selected*
2. Switch to object mode and add an empty (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)
3. With the empty selected (orange) and your non-cloth object active (yellow outline), enter edit mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *> Make vertex parent*:

   [image]
4. Back in object mode parent the cloth object to the empty by first selecting the cloth object, then the empty, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *> Object*.

Result (click for html5 video version):

[image: Example gif]

Comment: I get an error "loop in parents" when I attempt step #4.

Comment: "loop in parents"

Comment: @oxidworks Works for me. Is it possible you could upload your .blend somewhere?

Comment: I add a plane, add physics, subdivide, select vertex, cursor to center, object mode, add empty.
Then, additionaly add the place to your selection. Empty is orange. Change to edit mode (plane). [Ctrl] + [P], make vertex parent.  So, plane is now the parent of the empty. That's why it's logical that step 4 can not work.

Comment: But now I think you meant the cube as object. Making cube vertex parent for empty. But then you still have the problem, that simple parenting the empty to the "plane" has no effect for "plane" physic. https://ufile.io/p2enn

Comment: @oxidworks Ah no, by "object" I meant the non-cloth object you want the cloth to follow (if you look closely you can see the cube is in edit mode in the screenshot). I see how that was unclear, I've edited the question. The parent > child hierarchy should be non-cloth object > hook empty > cloth

Comment: @gandalf3 Do you think a similar technique should work for what I want to do with soft body objects (you may take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119540/how-to-pin-soft-body-objects-to-another-mesh))?

Comment: I have no idea what I just did, but thank :)

Answer (score 6):

I struggled a lot before figuring this one out:

Having an existing *cloth object* (the cloth) and *sticky object* (the object that the cloth will stick to)

- for the *cloth object*

  - In Edit Mode, select some vertices and create a new vertex group (<kbd>Space</kbd>, *Assign to New Group*)
    [image: Assign to New Group]
  - with those vertices selected, hook them to a new empty object (<kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, *Hook to New Object*)
    [image: Hook to New Object]
  - in the Modifiers tab, **Move the Hook modifier up**, before the Cloth Modifier
  - in the Cloth Modifier, activate Pinning, and set the pin the vertex group as the pinned vertices
    [image: Pin screenshot]

Then, in Object Mode Select the *empty object*, then the *sticky object*, and Press <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, *Object* (Set the parent of the *empty object* to  the *sticky object*)

[image: Set Parent to object]

You should then be set

[image]

Comment: wow, that is so cool! thanks

Answer (score 4):

The object in the hook modifier is the one you want the cloth to follow. This might be a characters body or you could select an armature and then a bone, such as the neck or hand.

There is a shortcut to creating hooks. Select the object you want to follow then shift select the cloth object and go into edit mode. Select the vertices you want to pin and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> and select Hook to Selected Object.

If you have an existing hook modifier there will be extra options to adjust the hook settings.

[image]

Comment: But which object do I want it to follow, the armature, the mesh, an empty which follows some part of the model... As said, I only have rotations.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the pinning in the Physics Tab with the Pinning Option of the Cloth Options. Then the verts of the group will follow the origin of your object.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need a hook.

Add a plane, subdivide and change to cloth.
Go to edit mode; select (pinned) vertex, create vertex group and assign.
Go to physics, activate pinning, select your vertex group.
You can now set any object as parent.

Comment: Do note that the cloth won't follow deformations of the parent object this way, if that's something you need.