# Attach cloth to solids and do animation

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to build an animation of a sail rising up a mast. Effectively, the sail is in several segments, so realistically, each segment intersection will move at slightly different rates. It will also collect on the deck. (I'm sure you can visualize it.)

First, is there a way of parenting two armatures to one segment, one on the top edge and one on the bottom. I know that a single armature can be used with two bones, but they only "attach" to the center of the edges, not the whole edge.

Second, I can't seem to get the bones to run along a curve independently from each other. If I could do that (and the connect to the whole edges) I can keyframe the movements closely enough.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14242/599

Comment: Why use different armatures? Wouldn't it be enough to use just a single armature with many bones? The sail should then be divided into vertex groups where the upper vertices of the sails are parented to the upper bone etc. Perhaps I just misunderstood your question....

Comment: "is there a way of parenting two armatures to one segment"  What does this mean?  What is a segment?  Are you sure you want to parent an armature to a segment, or do you want to parent a segment to an armature?

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting empties where you want to attach them to the cloth (you can parent vertices and empties), then parent the empties to the rope armature.