# HOw to attach cloth to rigged character same like ncloth of maya.?

Tags: rigging, constraints, weight-painting, cloth-simulation

I have problem with attaching cloths to my rigged character. I can simply attach cloth to rigged character by using automatic weight painting. but it is not working perfectly that i want.

In Maya we can create and attach n-cloth with using some constraints and weight transfers but how can i do same working dress in blender. any one can help me on this topic.

I know this will work in blender after some tricks, but i don`t know that.

Maya ncloth tutorial link is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asvSqkRGdlo).

Comment: Do ctrl+P It could help If not i dont know but i do want that bounty >:)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14242/599

Comment: can you make a video tutorial like above link. then bounty yours. because i cant do it my self. @gandalf3