# Stretching cloth to targets

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm competent enough with modelling objects, but I'm less experienced with cloth and I'm struggling with something. I've googled it, but can't find what I'm looking for, and for all I suspect I might need to use pinning somehow, since this is a static model I can't seem to make it work.

I've created an airship, as the pic below shows.

[image: airship pic]

The net suspends the gondola and spreads the weight over the top of the balloon. 
The version of the net I have so far is a plane, with the cloth modifier, and then I ran the simulation. The cloth fell nicely over it, but obviously only draped straight down. I then had to convert to mesh and use proportional editing to make the net look stretched to the gondola points.

What I really want to do is use cloth simulation properly to stretch the net to the anchor points of the gondola. I've tried hooking the edges to rigidbody spheres and letting them fall, I even tried using force fields to blow the material to where I want it, but no joy.

Can someone kindly tell me what I'm missing please?
Many thanks
Ian.

Comment: The same question was answered here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14242/pin-cloth-to-model

Answer (score 2):

A recent feature somewhere in 2.6x offered up called 'sewing springs' 
http://s6.postimg.org/s0xtlxxkx/sew_Spring0.gif

System depends upon edges to act as pull string, here's how.

Setup pinned vertex group to act as final 'pull' position and anchor. Have it be attached to cloth via extruded 'edges only'.
[image]

Followed by a group of edges to bridge distance by pulling.

Enable sewing springs and attach group. 
[image]

Add collision detection, bake, rinse and repeat.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need. Fantastic, Thankyou. I'll have a go when I can get to my computer tomorrow. 