# How to [dynamically] pin soft body objects to another mesh?

Tags: modeling, animation, armature, physics, soft-body

My goal is to use the [Armory](https://armory3d.org/) addon to move the two soft body meshes to interact some rigid bodies in the scene. For example, I want to apply forces the soft body objects to bring them closer to each other and grab something (a rigid body/collider mesh) in the scene. It is possible that those interactions would push each of the soft body meshes in different directions but I do not want this to be the case. Instead, I want the soft body meshes to be somehow linked to each other in a way that moving/interacting with one will affect the other one too (I basically want to build a simplified version of what is shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/QYrQnAKsLsQ?t=33) from the 33rd second to the first minute). For instance, if a colliding mesh contacts one of the soft body meshes with high velocity from any angle I would like the two soft bodies move in the same direction as a result of this collision.

Therefore, I am looking for a way to somehow glue/attach/pin two soft body objects to something (e.g. bone or another mesh) placed on top of them. However, just pinning the top vertices of the soft body meshes will disallow me to move them freely (as shown [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120020/how-to-make-a-specific-area-of-a-soft-body-behave-like-rigid-body-or-vice-versa)). So I want to have a more *flexible* type of pinning (hence the term "**dynamic**") so that the soft body meshes can still be moved towards each other when some force is applied to them so that they can interact/collide with other objects but don't fall down.

I wonder, how would this be possible? You can take a look at the *.blend* file that I attach to this question to get a better intuition of what I want to do. Here's a screenshot of the scene in the attached *.blend* file:

[image]

P.S. I'm not sure if the tag *animation* is correct for my question, but I thought it should be relevant. So feel free to edit the questions and remove if my question is not relevant to animation stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to 'pin' certain vertices of a soft body in place, you can use the Soft Body Goal settings with a Vertex Group.

First select the vertices that you want to pin in Edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). Then add a new Vertex Group and click 'Assign' to assign them to the group. Rename the vertex group to something appropriate such as "Pin".

[image: vertex group]

In the Soft Body Goal settings, set the Strength and Stiffness to high values (the closer to 1.0, the more the vertices will be attached in place to the vertices in the starting mesh that you have 'pinned'.

[image]

Only those vertices in the vertex group will be 'pinned' - the rest will continue to behave as Soft Body.

You can then either leave the original mesh in place (so it keeps those pinned vertices static) or Hook the vetices to another mesh so that they are pinned to that other mesh.

Comment: Thank you but how can I ensure both soft bodies have some sort of connection? Basically, I want these two soft bodies to behabe like two fingers(gripper). Maybe adding a bone between them be the solution?

Comment: Yeah, @Amir, this answer just relates to the specific question “I am looking for a way to somehow glue/attach/pin two soft body objets to a mesh (or an imaginary point) placed on top of them so that the soft body meshes can still interact/collide with other objects but don't fall down”. Your other question takes it further but here you’re just asking about the pinning.

Comment: I updated my question. Do you think you have a better idea on how I can achieve this?

Comment: @Amir You have confused me now.... why are you using **Soft** body simulation for that? From the video you now have linked to the question it all appears to be *rigid*. I was thinking that you were looking to create some kind of soft body tenticle that could be moved around - but still reacting to anything in its way (in which case I believe I now have a solution) - but it looks like it's something completely different that you are aiming for.

Comment: You were right. That's exactly what I need (soft body) but I posted this video only to make the idea more clear

Comment: @Amir I think I understand now - but you have two competing questions now - this one and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119812/. I’d suggest editing this one back to just be the pinning (in which case I believe my answer addresses it) and change the other answer to link to this one and requesting how to still move the end of it while the top is pinned. I can then provide an answer for the other question also. This site works best with single uncomplicated questions that can then remain for others’ benefit. I can edit the questions in that way for you if you so desire?

Comment: I’m thinking something like this : https://youtu.be/xNLtPLFECNw - just much simplified (not rippling, only one control point (at the end)).

Comment: Yes that behavior is somehow what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Amir I've posted an answer to the other question (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119812/) and updated that question to describe the 'tenticle' behaviour. That solution should provide the desired behaviour - just move the 'tip' control point wherever you want the tip to move.