# How to fold cloth

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, parent

I'm trying to fold cloth around a table to created a fitted look. I found someone who asked a question about pinning cloth to an object, which seems to do what I want, but there is a key difference; I need to do it with multiple objects.

The way I see it in my head, I would parent the cloth's corners to the object, and then move the objects into the location I need them in to fold the cloth how I want. Does anyone know how to do either this, or an easier way to fold cloth? Any help is appreciated!

Link to related question:
[Pin cloth to model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14242/pin-cloth-to-model)

Comment: Did you try vertex groups? And give a screenshot of what you want to do.

Comment: The cloth object can have multiple hooks setup, each linked to a different object. Unless you are animating the cloth being folded, you don't need the sim to fold some clothing. Just model it as if it was folded.

Comment: You can do it by modeling a cube to a narrow bar and give it a collision physics and put the cloth above it with a cloth simulation. Play the animation select the perfect frame apply the modifier .Move it where ever you want .

Answer (score 3):

In the future, it would be best to [add a .blend file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file) or to be more specific about your objectives. In lieu of this, here is a quick script that does folding and then unfolding of cloth. Hopefully you can build upon this for your own needs. I am using **Blender 2.82a**. Quick summary of the script:

- Removes starting cube and creates a supporting plane to go under the cloth.
- Creates the cloth via a plane and subdividing, and adds cloth modifier.
- Creates an armature, and assigns a vertex group to a designated index. (Unfortunately, finding desired vertex indices is sometimes challenging, and to start I [refer you to this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36577/how-are-vertex-indices-determined). The code is also somewhat delicate in that re-arranging some of the lines of code will lead to undesired results even if it seems harmless.)
- Assigns keyframes to the armature so that it will make a fold, and then an unfold because why not?

The script:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

def clear_scene():
    # Get rid of the starting cube..
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.data.objects['Cube'].select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

def make_supporting_plane():
    # Make an underlying plane to support cloth, with high cloth_friction.
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=6, location=(0, 0, 0))
    #bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(6.0, 6.0, 6.0))
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='COLLISION')
    bpy.context.object.collision.cloth_friction = 50

def make_cloth_and_arm():
    # Add the cloth. Tune the number of cuts for cloth detail.
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=3, location=(0, 0, 0.1))
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=20)
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='CLOTH')

    # Turn on collisions an increase the quality of the steps.
    cloth = bpy.data.objects["Plane.001"]
    cloth.modifiers["Cloth"].settings.quality = 10
    cloth.modifiers["Cloth"].collision_settings.collision_quality = 5
    cloth.modifiers["Cloth"].collision_settings.use_self_collision = True

    # Add armature, and make it the parent of the cloth. Creating the
    # armature 'deselects' cloth, so re-select cloth (in addition to armature).
    bpy.ops.object.armature_add(enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))
    arm = bpy.context.object
    cloth.select_set(True)

    # The arm must be the active object if it is the parent (else it's the child).
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = arm
    bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='ARMATURE_NAME')

    # Hard-code a vertex index to see which ones to pin. Look in edit mode.
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = cloth
    vertices_to_pin = [1]
    cloth_vgroup = cloth.vertex_groups.new(name='Pinned')
    cloth_vgroup.add(vertices_to_pin, 1.0, 'ADD')
    cloth.modifiers["Cloth"].settings.vertex_group_mass = cloth_vgroup.name

    # The modifier must be at the TOP of the modifier stack (over cloth)!
    for _ in range(3):
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up(modifier="Armature")

    # Need this to make armature move the vertices. But I'm not sure why it works. :)
    arm_group = bpy.context.object.vertex_groups["Bone"]
    arm_group.add(vertices_to_pin, 1.0, 'ADD')
    return (cloth, arm)

def animate(cloth, arm):
    # Select items, enter Pose mode.
    arm.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = arm
    bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()

    # Adjust keyframes of armature, which will move it along with cloth vertices.
    frames = [0, 30, 90, 120, 130, 160, 220, 250]
    bone = arm.pose.bones['Bone']
    bone.keyframe_insert("location", frame=frames[0])
    bone.location += Vector((0, 1, 0))
    bone.keyframe_insert("location", frame=frames[1])
    bone.location += Vector((-2, 0, -2))
    bone.keyframe_insert("location", frame=frames[2])
    bone.location += Vector((0, -1, 0))
    bone.keyframe_insert("location", frame=frames[3])
    bone.keyframe_insert("location", frame=frames[4]) # pause 10 frames
    bone.location += Vector((0, 1, 0))
    bone.keyframe_insert("location", frame=frames[5])
    bone.location += Vector((2, 0, 2))
    bone.keyframe_insert("location", frame=frames[6])
    bone.location += Vector((0, -1, 0))
    bone.keyframe_insert("location", frame=frames[7])

    # Back to Object mode.
    bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clear_scene()
    make_supporting_plane()
    cloth, arm = make_cloth_and_arm()
    animate(cloth, arm)
```

If the script is in `test.py`, then run `blender -P test.py` from the command line. Upon opening Blender, I click the cloth and **bake the simulation**. Then, I click "play," I see this in my screen recording:

[image]

Hope this helps!