# Why does it look like the Y and Z axes are swapped in the animation graph editor?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I am using the python script from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142348/how-to-fold-cloth) as a base to learn about clothing and animation.

However as I try to use the graph editor to change the movements I struggle because the Y and Z axes seem swapped in the editor:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why is that? what am I getting wrong?