# How to make a cloth affect a rigid body and simultaneously follow the rigid body?

Tags: animation, physics

I'd like to connect a rigid body and cloth for a sail animation, so when the rigid body is moving to the right when wind is blowing and the cloth is moving to the right I'd like for them to be connected and move together - like cloth is dragging the rigid body rather them moving separately.
How can I achieve this? I've tried solutions with hooks, and a few other things I've found here, but without success :(

<s>I have an example, of what I'd like to get, but not sure how I can attach it here :(</s>

[image]

Comment: maybe the cloth should be attached to the rigid body (with a parenting to vertex)? Also do you really need the object to be rigid body?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe not if there is a way to drag not rigid body object by attached cloth sail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a child of constraint to your cloth sail and add the rigid body to the influence object. That way, the cloth will move with the rigid body. If you want the rigid body to be affected by the cloth, so then you're probably using a force to make the cloth move: so definitely the rigid body will be affected by that force, so it will visually look like the sail is affecting the movement.

Edit: You've done two things wrong. First thing, make the sail the child of the stick, not the stick the child of the sail. Second thing you have to do is to hook the vertex of your object to an empty like this: [Pin cloth to model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14242/pin-cloth-to-model)

Comment: That sounds awesome, I'll give it a try, thanks

Comment: @Larumis Don't forget to give the cloth a hook/pin group so it doesn't fall dawn and result in a torn-up destroyed sail !)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work or I have done it incorrectly - the lag between cloth and rigid body is huge and also rigid body is not connected to the right side of the sail. Also constraints moves around origin, meaning that I cannot have box collision shape I think :(
[Blender example file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/XbpZ6BkA/)

Comment: Hmmm wait, let me test it practically on your file and I'll update you soon, @Larumis

Comment: Check my edits @Larumis

Comment: Amazing - it works ! Thank you !